# Install4j: Launched app displays separate JavaApplicationStub in dock

Tags: java, macos, install4j

When we converted our application from Java 5/6 to Java 7, the icon installed on the Dock no longer behaves as expected.  Previously, the icon on the Dock would launch our application, and would then show as being the active application, as is normal for MacOS.

When we switched to Java 7, the installed Dock icon bounces when clicked, briefly changes to a generic window icon, then reverts and becomes inactive.  In its place a new icon appears on the Dock (as for an application which was not already kept in the Dock), with the correct appearance, but with the title JavaApplicationStub.  If the user then selects Options->Keep In Dock on this application, the icon reverts to what appears to be a generic console app icon on exit.

I know that JavaApplicationStub is the name of the actual executable launched by MacOS X, which then launches the JVM.  What I don't understand is why our application is no longer showing its actual title, nor why a new icon appears while it's running.

I have attempted to resolve this by adding CFBundleDisplayName to the generated Info.plist, along with the necessary InfoPlist.strings file (in Contents/Resources/en.lproj), but this didn't change anything.

Interestingly, I have also observed Install4j itself revert to this behavior, after the Dock gets updated by running a generated installer.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there an option in Install4j I should have changed when switching from Java 5/6 (using Apple JRE) to Java 7 (using bundled JRE 1.7.0_67)?

**More Detail:** We have the Install4j generated launcher invoke a stub jar file, which among other things performs a "silent update" self-patching operation.  Once updates, if any, have been applied, we launch our main application using a new instance of a `URLClassLoader` within the same JVM, as follows:

```
URLClassLoader cload = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new java.net.URL[]{new java.io.File(silentUpdate.getLocalInstallFolder() + FILENAME_JAR).toURI().toURL()});
Class<?> cl = cload.loadClass(MAIN_CLASS);
Method startMethod = cl.getMethod("main", new Class[]{String[].class});
startMethod.invoke(cl, new Object[]{args});
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that here. Can you check if you get the same behavior with the "samples/hello.install4j" project and the "Hello GUI" launcher?

Comment: A fellow engineer on our team established that the problem has to do with the fact that we launch our application using a stub jar file, which then loads the main application jar file via a new instance of a URLClassLoader.  When we bypassed this stub, the application launched as expected.  Is there something we should be doing differently with this secondary classloader to keep windows launched by it tied to the same launch icon?

Comment: This kind of icon problem would occur if you actually launched a new JVM. Is that what is happening in your case?

Comment: I would understand this behavior if we were launching a new JVM, but we aren't; I've added some detail showing what we do.

Comment: That seems strange. However, install4j sets the dock icon with a standard VM parameter and is not running any code at this point. It seems that this would also happen without install4j, if you set an initial dock icon with -Xdock:icon=/path/to/icon